# Paypal sandbox not reflecting transactions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, paypal-sandbox

Yet another question about sandbox transactions...

On https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts/ I have 2 sandbox accounts:

- [business] bob-facilitator@domain.com
- [personal] bob-buyer@domain.com

In my rails config I'm using activemerchant and I've set up my PaypalExpressGateway credentials using the API credentials from the business account above:

`ActiveMerchant::Billing::Base.mode = :test
  ::GATEWAY = ActiveMerchant::Billing::PaypalExpressGateway.new(
    login: ENV['BOB-FACILITATOR-USERNAME']
    password: ENV['BOB-FACILITATOR-PASSWORD']
    signature: ENV['BOB-FACILITATOR-SIGNATURE']
  )`

I've got an orders controller and when I click a 'buy' button, the controller redirects the user to `::GATEWAY.redirect_url_for(paypal_response.token)`. This in my case means the user is redirected to:

```
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=A_TOKEN_FROM_PAYPAL
```

Then in the sandbox paypal store I login successfully with the buyer's account and click the continue button representing payment. I'm successfully redirected back to my success_url and receive what look like some successful params:

`/orders/success/6?token=SAME_TOKEN_FROM_PAYPAL_AS_THE_ONE_ABOVE&PayerID=THE_PAYER_ID_OF_SANDBOX_BUYER_ACCOUNT`

Ok so cool the transaction is finished but when I log into the sandbox paypal site with either the buyer or seller's login details, no transactions are listed. When I'm logged into my main paypal developer account, I also cannot see any transactions.

What is happening? Where can I find either the transactions or some debugging information?

Comment: Did you find the solution of your issue, I'm also getting the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Try with below steps:

- Login to your sandbox business account
- Then click on below url
- https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/businessexp/transactions

It will show you all transactions with every currency. This is because sometimes a transaction is not listed in the account overview page in the sandbox, but it does show up in the activity page. Account overview and activity pages are different and also have different layouts.

If your transaction is not listed here, then create ticket on PayPal merchant portal

Thanks
NK

Comment: You are essentially repeating what the OP stated he had already done, with no success, so this is not an answer like this, also saying "create a ticket" should be posted as a comment rather than an answer as well.

Comment: Balazs, Sometime transaction is not listed in account overview page in sandbox, but it is showing in activity page.
account overview and activity page are different and also having different layouts,
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/businessexp/transactions

Comment: then I must have misunderstood you, my apologies. Such not so self-outcalling parts should be explicitly stated and perhaps emphasized in your answer though.

Comment: Thanks Balazs, Noted :)

Comment: As I said, and as Balázs has reiterated, the transactions page for my buyer sandbox account is empty. Thanks for the attempt though.